# Shell Read File Line by Line Issue

Tags: bash, shell, dig

Let's say i have a file(`Input.txt`) with some following dig commands.

```
dig NS google.com
dig NS box.com
dig NS dropbox.com
dig NS cnn.com
dig NS bbc.co.uk
```

I want to execute the dig commands from the file only and which has to be read line by line.

Currently i tried using

```
for i in $(cat Input.txt);do $i;done
```

I'm not sure,how this can be executed and i get the following message as command not found.

Any suggestions please on resolving this issue ?

Comment: or just `sh Input.txt`.

Comment: @Kenney : Thanks mate !

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
. Input.txt
```

A dot followed by a space and file name will execute each line in the file.

Your `for` loop doesn't work because it is splitting up the input by word, not by line.  So it's trying to execute the command `google.com`, for instance, hence the "command not found" messages.

Comment: Nicely done; to complement your answer, here's [a link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) that explains the problem with using `for` to parse command in more detail and how to do it right (_if_ it is needed).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .sh file and place commands redirecting the outputs, eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

dig NS google.com >> ~/google.log
dig NS box.com >> ~/box.log
dig NS dropbox.com
dig NS cnn.com
dig NS bbc.co.uk
```

Comment: His file already *is* a script, and your output redirections are just gratuitous additions.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for the `eval` keyword.  So, with your general example:

```
cat Input.txt | while read i;do eval $i;done
```

Personally, I'd be inclined to suggest that the better way to do this specific thing would be to have your list of domains, and do something like:

```
xargs -n 1 -a /file/with/domains dig NS
```

Depending on your data source, the xargs solution might be significantly more secure than just running whatever command is in a file.  But that obviously depends upon what's in your real data file.

Comment: `i` doesn't iterate over complete lines; it iterates over whitespace-separated words.

Comment: Oh dang it. It's been a long day. Fixed.

Comment: ... Almost fixed by setting `$IFS=\n`